# AppStore Push issue with appcelerator

Tags: ios, app-store, titanium-mobile

I was developed an application using titanium-Appcelerator. I was stuck with

`Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format'`

`Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format`

`Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format`

error while submitting titanium application to AppStore. I developed this application in "CLASSIC'' framework in Titanium. I had referred to many docs and forums regards this issue.

I had tried by setting appicon names as " `appicon-60@2x.png,appicon-76@2x.png,appicon-76.png`, etc as per guidelines in `Project-Name/Resources/iPhone` even it was showing the above issue repeatedly while submitting.

Answer (score 1):

What is the list of `.png` filenames you have in `Resources/iphone`?

The files you need for the sizes you list are:

- `appicon-60@2x.png` (120x120)
- `appicon-76.png` (76x76)
- `appicon-76@2x.png` (152x152)

You could use the [TiCons CLI](http://npmjs.com/ticons) to generate all the icons using a single 2048x2048 file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue even though I had all the files correctly named and in the right directory.

I was able to validate my app successfully after cleaning the project in Appcelerator Studio (`Project -> Clean`), and re-running the distribution build. Subsequent builds would not pass validation (same error) unless I cleaned again in between builds.

(I am using Titanium 7.1.0.GA, Appcelerator Studio 5.0.0.201712081732, and Xcode 9.3)